# nginx: how to serve files in gzip format when client accepts "Accept-Encoding: gzip" and inflated otherwise?

Tags: nginx, gzip, http-headers, encoding

I have a folder full of `.gz` files and would like to serve them transparently inflated if requested by a client that does *not* send `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in the request and as-is (`gzip`'d) otherwise.

I know there is the [`HttpGzipStaticModule`](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpGzipStaticModule) module, but that only solves one part of the problem. The files will *only* be stored as `.gz`, so there won't be an inflated version there for `nginx` on the file system. This shouldn't be a performance issue, since inflate is fairly light on CPU and RAM.

What method can I use to inflate the `.gz` file on-the-fly and serve it back to the client? Do I have to script it and use a rewrite or is there something builtin that I just haven't found as of yet?

Comment: You store the gunzipped files as well, or you write your own "GunzipStatic" module.